# Why is image stored different than the one imshowed?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, librosa

I am currently not able to understand why I am not able to recreate the plot after I store the data..

```
import os
import sys
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import seaborn as sb
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm
from PIL import Image
import librosa
import librosa.display
import ast

def make_plot_store_data(name,interweaved):
    librosa.display.specshow(interweaved.T,sr=16000,x_axis='frames',y_axis='mel',hop_length=160,cmap=cm.jet)
    plt.title("log mel power spectrum of interweaved " + name)
    plt.colorbar(format='%+02.0f dB')
    plt.savefig(plot+"/"+name+"_plot_interweaved_conv.png")
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


    convert = plt.get_cmap(cm.jet)
    numpy_output_interweawed = convert(interweaved.T)
    print interweaved.shape
    print numpy_output_interweawed.shape
    plt.imshow(numpy_output_interweawed, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.show()
    raw_input("Somethign")
    numpy_output_interweawed.dump(numpy_train+name+"_normalized_interweaved"+".dat")
    numpy_output_interweawed_or = convert(interweaved.T)*255
    numpy_output_interweawed_or.dump(numpy_train+name+"_interweaved"+".dat")
```

The plot showed by `librosa` views the data as

[image]

But when i convert the raw data using `plt.cmap(cm.jet)`
and the  plot it using `matplotlib.pyplot` something messes up with the data, and doesn't look like the original in any way..

[image]

**Edit**

This is with

```
plt.imshow(interweaved.T,aspect = 'auto')
plt.show()
raw_input("Somethign")
```

[image]

It seem like the aspect ratio of the image matter - it begins to resemble the original plot, when I make the plot bigger - But why are the colors so dark...

[image]

Comment: Same question as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647366/store-a-numpy-ndarray-as-an-image-and-then-save-the-pixel-values

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong, everything seems to work as expected as far as I can tell without having the data or knowing the array shapes.

However, if you want to have your [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html) plot look similar to the one produced by librosa, you may first consider to use an unequal aspect

```
plt.imshow(...,  aspect="auto")
```

and possibly set the data range of the plot correctly using the `extent` argument of imshow.

Also be aware that the plot produced by librosa is a  `pcolormesh`, so to truely replicate it, you might want to keep your data in the format it is (not putting it through a colormap) and use `pcolormesh` to plot it.

Comment: array shape of interweaved is (x,40).  when it has been cmap converted it is (40,x,4) - which is also what I would expect.  but the plot just looks so different.  Why do i need `pcolormesh`  when `cmap` should have created a data array with RGB values.  The data has to contain the RGB values of the image as I store them later on for further processing.

Comment: And do you know why the grid appears?