# Store a numpy.ndarray as an image, and then save the pixel values

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, colormap

I am currently looking for at in which i can store a `numpy.ndarray` as an image, then save that image, and extract the pixel values of the image into a `numpy.ndarray`. The dimension of the numpy.ndarray with the pixel values should be the same as the numpy.ndarray what was used to create the plot.

I tried something like this:

```
def make_plot_store_data(name, data):
    plt.figure()
    librosa.display.specshow(data.T,sr=16000,x_axis='frames',y_axis='mel',hop_length=160,cmap=cm.jet)
    plt.savefig(name+".png")
    plt.close()

    convert = plt.get_cmap(cm.jet)
    numpy_output_interweawed = convert(data.T)
```

The first image looks like this: 
[image]
The second image looks like this:

[image]

Why is this so messed up?

Comment: It's easier to help when you provide a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, it's not clear why your `ndarray` would change shape just because it's rendered as an image.  See my answer below for a working example.

Comment: Also, your `convert()` maps scalars to RGBA, which will return an `[N, N, 4]` matrix, given an `[N x N]` input array.  See [`Colormap` docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap) for more.

Comment: Same question as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646838/why-is-image-stored-different-than-the-one-imshowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach that takes a 512x512 `ndarray`,  displays it as an image, stores it as an image object, saves an image file, and generates a normalized pixel array of the same shape as the original.

```
import numpy as np

# sample numpy array of an image
from skimage import data
camera = data.camera()
print(camera.shape) # (512, 512)

# array sample
print(camera[0:5, 0:5])

[[156 157 160 159 158]
 [156 157 159 158 158]
 [158 157 156 156 157]
 [160 157 154 154 156]
 [158 157 156 156 157]]

# display numpy array as image, save as object
img = plt.imshow(camera)
```

[image: camera]

```
# save image to file
plt.savefig('camera.png')

# normalize img object pixel values between 0 and 1
normed_pixels = img.norm(camera)

# normed_pixels array has same shape as original 
print(normed_pixels.shape) # (512, 512)

# sample data from normed_pixels numpy array 
print(normed_pixels[0:5,0:5])

[[ 0.61176473  0.6156863   0.627451    0.62352943  0.61960787]
 [ 0.61176473  0.6156863   0.62352943  0.61960787  0.61960787]
 [ 0.61960787  0.6156863   0.61176473  0.61176473  0.6156863 ]
 [ 0.627451    0.6156863   0.60392159  0.60392159  0.61176473]
 [ 0.61960787  0.6156863   0.61176473  0.61176473  0.6156863 ]]
```

You might consider looking into the [`skimage`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html) module, in addition to standard `pyplot` methods.  There are a bunch of image manipulation methods there, and they're all built to play nice with `numpy`.  Hope that helps.